# scatter plot for kmeans versus other variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to see how data is clustered in a dataframe with multiple variables and confused about how to cluster is effectively.

[image]

This is the dataframe basically,

usually i use this sort of script to make a scatter plot against one variable, but with multiple it's really not working,

```
x, y = noevent_cluster['disgusted'],noevent_cluster['angry']
c = noevent_cluster['kmeans_4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c)

# produce a legend with the unique colors from the scatter
legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
                    loc="upper right", title="Clusters")
ax.add_artist(legend1)

plt.show()

# plt.scatter(testthis['feature1'], testthis['feature2'], c=testthis['kmeans_4'],label=testthis['kmeans_4'])
```

Any good approaches on visualization for this sort of dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')

plt.scatter(x=df.index,y=df['angry'],c=df['kmeans_4'])
plt.show()
```

This is example code, You can try.

Comment: Thanks - I want to use all the columns in the cluster though

Comment: You can use X = df for all column.

Comment: I edited new code try again, I think your code have kmean column already so used it for scatter plot.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I suppose, I have like, Angry, Sad, Surprised, etc as columns, trying to work out best way to display all of them to see how the clusters move about